# Is there any impact to Android/iOS WebView when I renew our API URL's SSL cert?

Tags: android, ios, ssl, webview, https

My questions is about I have some mobile applications (both Android and iOS) in hand now and it's working fine.

The flow of my app is it has to call some URL for REST API and open some WebView content with https:// but now the SSL Cert is going to be expired soon.

My concern is if I renew the SSL Cert on that REST API server, is there any impact to my current Android and iOS application when they call the URL?

It will be good if everything is still the same when I renew SSL cert on the server :)

Comment: are you using SSL pinning in the App?

Comment: not sure, I'm the API developer on server side not mobile app developer so I will ask them soon. But could you please explain what is SSL pinning ? And how it helps our problem if we are using it.

Comment: SSL Pinning is where you manually pin the HTTP to a certain SSL certificate. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#Pinning

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sure that they don't use it because no manual HTTP config like you said in the app.